# How can I write field definition in Pyparsing so following error does not occur

Tags: python, pyparsing

Suppose I want to parse following statement:

```
CREATE VIEW View_1 AS
SELECT sampleTable.empId,
       sampleTable.empName,
       sampleTable.dateJoining
FROM sampleTable
INNER JOIN TestTable ON sampleTable.empId = TestTable.empId
```

This is my sample code.

```
create_view_def = Literal("CREATE") + "VIEW" + Word(alphas, alphanums+"_") + "AS"
select_def = Literal("SELECT")
field_def = OneOrMore(Word(alphas, alphanums+"_\"':.-"))
# field_list_def = delimitedList(field_def, delim=",")
field_list_def = Group(delimitedList(field_def, delim=","))
select_all_def = select_def + field_list_def
from_def = Literal("FROM") + Word(alphas, alphanums+"_")
check_def = create_view_def + select_all_def + from_def
l = check_def.parseString(query)
print(l)
```

I am getting error:
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "FROM", found '='
I expected to parse till FROM then add definition for JOIN

Comment: Excellent first question posted to SO - you included the sample text and your code attempts, without including hundreds of lines of extra code!

Comment: You may be able to solve this for yourself by adding some pyparsing debugging. The root problem is the `field_def` is reading the `FROM` as part of a field, not as the `FROM` keyword. You'll see this if you add `field_def.setName("field_def").setDebug()` and view the tokens that get matched. To fix, you should add a negative lookahead in `field_def` to *not* match on the keyword `FROM`, or add a `stopOn=` argument to `OneOrMore`. You might also get some ideas from browsing the various SQL parsers in the pyparsing examples directory on github.

Comment: Thanks, `stopOn` is working, since FROM cannot be used as column names